# Christian Flag symbol

Tags: protestantism, symbolism

I have seen a symbol on my way to work and am wondering what it means. It is a flag with a Red Cross on a black background and there is a red upside down triangle in the upper right corner that touches the cross. Is it just a variation of the Christian Flag?

Comment: Can  you show us a picture of this flag and the name of the building or church that displays these colors?

Comment: It's certainly not a duplicate of that question, but I've voted to close because it's not clear why the flag is assumed to be related to Christianity.

Comment: The OP seems to be asking about the symbolism on the flag  and not whether the flag is a Christian symbol?

Comment: You're certain the triangle is pointing down? If so, I'd say based on the symbols it is a Christian Gay group. But it's impossible to say without a detailed description or photo. Not a duplicate, though. Just unclear.